# Unable to understand a line

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

[image]

I am unable to understand the conclusion lines in the attached solution image. Here u=sup S>r, it may occur, but book mentioned it as contradiction. Please elaborate the conclusion part only.

Comment: Are you referring to the conclusion starting with "(ii) show that $r$ is...?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it may not occur. By definition, the supremum is the *least* upper bound. In (ii) it is shown that $r$ is an upper bound*, and in (i) it is shown that $r$ is less than $u,$ so $u$ is not the *least* upper bound.

*To check this, we need to show that $r$ is greater than any element of $S.$ For any $x \in S,$ we have $x^2 < 2$ by definition. So $r^2 > 2 > x^2,$ and thus by taking square roots, $|r| > \sqrt{2} > |x|.$ But $x$ is positive by definition of $S,$ and $r$ is positive as argued, so the absolute value bars are unnecessary, and we have $r > x.$

Comment: Why r is upper bound, from (ii)?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @user1942348: I have updated my answer to address this question.